# Access an attribute value from another jsp In jquery

Tags: jquery, jsp

I have 2 jsp's. editAttribute.jsp & securitySetting.jsp

And having a Hidden variable in form which is to be posted in editAttribute.jsp (which is an individual page).

```
<input type="hidden" name="securitySetting" id="securitySetting" value="">
```

and have some radio options in securitySetting.jsp(another Page)

I need to set the hidden variable value based on the value which I selected in securitySettings.jsp

```
var sectype = $("input:radio[name='secType']:checked").val();
if (sectype == 'open') {
  $("#securitySetting").val("N");
  console.log("In open" + $("#securitySetting").val());
} else if (sectype == 'restricted') {
  var sg = $("#sgrp").val();
  $("#securitySetting").val(sg);
  console.log("In restricted" + $("#securitySetting").val());
}
```

But I could nt get the control of the `$("#securitySetting")` object in this current page. 
How can I access the the hidden input object of editAttribute page from here.

ANy ways of achieving this???

Comment: you need to post data in order to access that variable at second page.

Comment: How do I post?? Sorry i couldnt get you @DipeshParmar

Comment: there are two pages right.?? so all you can do is post form from one page to other with security setting input as hidden and get that posted field on second page...sorry if i am wrong, i just trying to help you..